# convert from HTML TO MS Word

Tags: .net

I want to convert editor content to a Word document. I am using asp.net with VB code.

How can I do that and which library should I use?

Answer (score 0):

There's a code extract in the bottom post of [this forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1505667.aspx). The full site that code is from can be found [here](http://aspalliance.com/794_Dynamic_Generation_of_Word_Document_Report_in_ASPNET_with_HTML)