# Error when converting from HTML to Word

Tags: asp.net, html, ms-word

When I convert the HTML content to MS Word, a thread aborted error message occurs. Below is the error log:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = ""
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/msword"

Dim strFileName As String = "GenerateDocument" + ".doc"
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + strFileName)

Dim strHTMLContent As New StringBuilder()
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTMLContent)

HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
```

Comment: Careful; the elitists are out in force voting down left and right... you might want to provide some more information like what the error message is, and what you're trying to do ;)

Comment: @Richard: I don't think it's fair to say the elitists are out. I think this site relies on a two way stream and some etiquette. If people want a decent answer, the least they could do is provide a decent question (or money ;)). A downvote signifies a poorly worded question. Also, I don't think this site is a place to simply ask questions and not respond to the replies (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081631/convert-from-html-to-ms-word)

Comment: I agree with everything you say, and I suppose I should direct an apology towards "the community". Let the record show, however, that attacking someone based on "the way you type" like this is a failure of such said etiquette, helping no one, and giving a bad first impression of "the community" for someone who joined today and whose first question is this.

(I'm beginning to feel kind of elitist myself... It feels good :O)

Comment: @Richard - lol, you do have a point. When English isn't your first language, it's understandable. But when you're missing letters off words you obviously know ('Conver' instead of 'Convert'), it seems like a rush job. Also, this question is related to the first question they posted (link in previous comment), but there was no feedback in the first post (positive or negative), so there's no incentive to help further. But you're right, a few chances should be given :) [Just to add, I didn't downvote]

Comment: @TenaciousImply - You make good points.

Thank you, I appreciate your reason and amicability.

Comment: @Richard: A good discussion is always fun :)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Response.End()` always results in a `ThreadAbortException`.

Is that causing any problems or are you just wondering why it is happening?

Also, I see in your code you are declaring a new `StringBuilder`, never adding any text to it, and then writing it out to the response. This will always be empty - is that deliberate?